# The show event is not fired using bootbox dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootbox

I'd like to catch the show event for the bootbox.confirm dialog to do some css adjustments to the dialog before showing that.

I tried things like the followings but didn't succeed:

```
$(document).on("show", function (event) {...});
$(document).on("show", ".bootbox", function (event) {...});
$(document).on("show.bs.modal", function (event) {...});
```

Answer (score 1):

They aren't global events. They are restricted to the plugin.

So you should use them within that context.

Like:

```
$('div').modal({
   show: function(){
     // do something
   }
});
```